# USB flash stick attaches but mount fails

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage, opensuse-13.2

When I plug-in my 16GB *Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive* into my *openSUSE 13.2 (Linux 3.16.7-35-desktop x86_64 GNU/Linux)* system, I get the following from `journalctl -f`:

```
kernel: scsi 25:0:0:0: Direct-Access  Generic USB Flash Disk 7.76 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
kernel: sd 25:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
kernel: sd 25:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

but `fdisk -l` only shows `/dev/sda1` through `/dev/sda7` - no `/dev/sdbX`; and it can't find `/dev/sdb`, either:

```
jsn-dev:/home/jan # /usr/sbin/fdisk /dev/sdb

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.25.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: No medium found
```

The USB subsystem does seem to find it, however:

```
jsn-dev:/home/jan # lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0451:8044 Texas Instruments, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0451:8044 Texas Instruments, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0451:8046 Texas Instruments, Inc. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 046d:c326 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0451:8044 Texas Instruments, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04ca:0061 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 058f:1234 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive               <-- 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I can't write over the partition table with `dd` also fails:

```
jsn-dev:/home/jan # dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb
dd: failed to open ‘/dev/sdb’: No medium found
```

I have tried all the USB ports in my `Dell T7610` system with the same results.

Any ideas how I can debug this further?

Comment: How is the USB device formatted? If exFAT, either install exfat-utils or reformat to FAT. See http://www.howtogeek.com/235655/how-to-mount-and-use-an-exfat-drive-on-linux/

Comment: I don't know what format it is, @DrMoishePippik, but the fact that `dd` fails to open the device leaves me to believe it's a more fundamental problem...perhaps the storage has failed.

Comment: have you tried `insf -e` as root ?

Comment: @Archemar -- no; I have not tried to reinstall the device with `/dev/MAKEDEV` (which I think is the GNU/Linux equivalent to HP-UX's `insf -e`), but given that my other USB devices work, including other flash drives, it seems unlikely that it's a driver issue -- do you agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stick is mostly dead.

`No Medium Found` basically means that the controller cannot "get in touch" with the storage memory. One of the cases is, for example, a card reader without a card inside it.

If you're "lucky" enough, the stick you got can actually be a "fake" flash drive that is actually a microSD + reader:

[image]

You can see that the solid half of the type-A USB plug has two layers, and the thicker layer is actually a microSD.

In this case, you can try to "pick" the card out with, for example, a "thin" slotted screwdriver:

[image]

Then you might get in return a working microSD with all the data intact.

But of course, you do not want to do this if it still got warranty and you prefer a replacement than the data.